# dates cannot be shown on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having difficulty showing a string separated with dates on a basic high chart

I am getting and saving the tweets from twitter into arrays and then converting the array into a string separated by commas and quotes.
Unfortunately I cant display them on the graph, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
    function search(){
    var value = $('#box').val();
    var array=[];
    var dateArray = [];
    var dateString;
    if (value!==""){$.getJSON("",
      function(data){

   $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
      var user=item.from_user;
      var created_at=new Date(item.created_at);
      var month = created_at.getMonth();
      var day = created_at.getDate();
      var year = created_at.getFullYear();
      var created= day +'/'+ month+ '/'+ year;
      array.push({date:created,username:user});
     });
    //    console.log(array);
    for (var i in array) {
        dateArray.push(array[i].date);
            }  
    dateString="'" + dateArray.join("','") + "'";
    console.log(dateString);
    });
      }
    var chart;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [dateString]
    },
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example? What do you mean you can't get them "on" the graph? Are they values or tooltips/titles?

Comment: @EricG http://jsfiddle.net/ang3lo0o/yPU67/ they are values and am trying to pass them over the graph's categories section

Comment: Alright, so I do "get" with input "a" and I get Tokyo, NY, Berlin, London. You want to display them at the legend right? I'll have a look.

Comment: no not on the legend. on the x-axis, in the categories [HERE]

Comment: I updated my post, it should work now :)

Comment: I think you will have to clarify the goal what you want to achieve. Consider the data from http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=spiderman&rpp=10 (I took 'spiderman' as example query). Use search (Ctrl-F) to highlight 'created_at'. You will see that the last 10 tweets will be all the same day, right (different time). So it will display in your graph, as the same day, too. Also, the 'series' data from the highchart (london, tokyo.., are static) have no relation with the dates from the tweets we are displaying (dynamic from the query). So what do you want to achieve/how can I help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fixed JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPU67/55/)

Your x-axis parameter should be as follows:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: dateString
    },
```

Als, just change this :-)

```
for (var i in array) {
    dateString.push(array[i].date);
}  

highchart(dateString);
```

Oh, and you should change to this, definately.

```
<input type="text" id="box" value="a"/>
```

**Extra investigation info:**
It appeared that (in the old situation)

```
console.log(stringArray);
highchart(stringArray);
```

was empty. Would you pass

```
highchart(["ab", "b", "c"]);
```

then you'd be fine. This is because you are passing an empty array, you are creating the chart before you have the JSON data. I therefore moved the creation to the JSON function.

Comment: why the month is always the 7th(july).something is wrong @EricG

Comment: Because you are creating new adate() everytime, it will give you 'today'. Tomorrow I'll have a look to see if I can find out what you tried to do :))

Comment: Look the comment in the other post please :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use xAxis as [datetime](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--type):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
```

Parse the dates into JS time from the twitter data and have something like this as your series data array:

```
[[<jstime1>, "big cool tweet1"], [<jstime2>, "big cool tweet2"]]
```